# How to rewrite $\int\limits_A^B \frac{x^n \exp(-\alpha x)}{\small(x + \beta\small)^m} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, special-functions

Currently, I am a post-graduate researcher in Telecommunications. During the process of evaluating the transmission error probability, I need to evaluate the following integral $I = \int\limits_A^B \frac{x^n \exp(-\alpha x)}{\small(x + \beta\small)^m} \, dx$?

How to rewrite this improper integral in terms of special function (for example $Ei(x)$, Bessel,...)?

Notice that $A, B, \alpha,\beta > 0$ (positive real number) and $m,n$ are two positive integers.

I have tried to compute this integral with different values of $A, B, \alpha,\beta > 0$ and $m,n$  by using Wolfram Mathematica.

It seems that the results of this integral have a form of the exponential integral function $Ei\left( x \right) = \int\limits_{t =  - x}^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - t}}}}{t}dt}  = \int\limits_{t =  - \infty }^{t = x} {\frac{{{e^t}}}{t}dt}$ as:

$I = C_1\bigg[C_2 + C_3\big[ {\rm Ei}\big(- \alpha(\beta+ A)\big) - {\rm Ei}\big(- \alpha(\beta+ B)\big) \big] \bigg]$.

Are there any way to find out the correct values of $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$.

Thank you for your enthusiasm!

Comment: One solves equations; one solves problems. One does not _solve_ expressions; one _evaluates_ them. "Solve" is the wrong word.

Comment: You should see this [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a question. One thing to note is that you should add more context and research on how to solve the problem. Welcome to MSE!

Comment: Did you notice that the problem is simple if $\beta=0$ ? Then ...

Comment: By $a$ and $b$, do you mean $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for considering my concern.

I have found out myself.

For the given integral above, I firstly change variable $y = x + \beta \to dx = dy$. Now, $I$ can be rewritten as

$I = \int_{y_{\min}}^{y_{\max}}\frac{\small(y - \beta\small)^n \exp\big(- \alpha\small(y-\beta\small)\big)}{y^m}dy$, where $y_{\min} = A +\beta$ and $y_{\max} = B + \beta$.

By using the binomial theorem for $\small(y - \beta\small)^n$, we can be modified $I$ as

$I = \exp(\alpha\beta)\sum_\limits{k=0}^n\binom{k}{n}\small(-\beta\small)^{n-k}
\int_{y_{\min}}^{y_{\max}}\frac{\exp\big(- \alpha y\big)}{y^{m-k}}dy$.

Based on the condition of $(m-k)$ and thanks to the help of Wolfram Mathematica, I can achieve the final result of $I$ as follows:

$\begin{array}{l}
I = \exp \left( {\alpha \beta } \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\
k
\end{array}} \right){{\left( { - \beta } \right)}^{n - k}}} \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \times \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{\alpha ^{ - \left( {m - k} \right) - 1}}\left[ {\Gamma \left( {\left( {m - k} \right) + 1,{y_{\min }}\alpha } \right) - \Gamma \left( {\left( {m - k} \right) + 1,{y_{\max }}\alpha } \right)} \right],m - k = 0\\
{\alpha ^{\left( {m - k} \right) - 1}}\left[ {\Gamma \left( {1 - \left( {m - k} \right),{y_{\min }}\alpha } \right) - \Gamma \left( {1 - \left( {m - k} \right),{y_{\max }}\alpha } \right)} \right],m - k \ne 0
\end{array} \right.
\end{array}$,

where $\Gamma \left(\cdot,\cdot\right)$ is upper bound incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: Thank you ! such a nice answer !

Answer (score 5):

Consider the integral

$$
I(\alpha)= \int\limits_{A}^{B} dx \ \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{(x+\beta)^m}
$$

By changing variables $y=x+\beta$, then scaling: $t=y/(A+\beta),$ this is in the form of two '[En-Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html)' , defined as $\operatorname{Ei}_n(x)=\int\limits_1^\infty dt \ t^{-n}e^{-xt} $  so we have

$$
I(\alpha)=e^{\alpha \beta}(\beta+A)^{1-m}\operatorname{Ei}_m(\alpha(\beta+A))-e^{\alpha \beta}(\beta+B)^{1-m}\operatorname{Ei}_m(\alpha(\beta+B))
$$

The original integral is given by the $n$th derivative of $I(\alpha)$

$$
\int\limits_{A}^{B} dx \ \frac{x^n e^{-\alpha x}}{(x+\beta)^m}=(-1)^n\frac{d^n }{d\alpha^n}I(\alpha)
$$

You may write $\operatorname{Ei}_m$, and consequently $I(\alpha)$, in terms of only $\operatorname{Ei}_1$, the exponential integral. The formula is given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html)

$$
\operatorname{Ei}_m(x)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\left[(-x)^{m-1}\operatorname{Ei}_1(x)+e^{-x}\sum\limits_{s=0}^{m-2}(m-s-2)!(-x)^s \right]
$$

Comment: This looks like a Feynman trick ? How can you even come up with this idea ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Yes this is a Feynman trick. It's really useful to remember when you have a exponential next to some power of $x$. Once we 'forget' about the $x^n$, I asked Mathematica if the integral with $\beta=0$ has a nice solution, because we can effectively set $\beta=0$ by changing variables. It turns out *that* integral is expressed in terms of a generalized exponential integral...

Comment: Thank you ! but is there any recurrence relationship to evaluate $\frac{{{d^n}}}{{d{\alpha ^n}}}I\left( \alpha  \right)$ ?. It seems to me that this approach require the OP to calculate the $n^{th}$ order derivative of the non-elementary function $E{i_m}\left( x \right)$.

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Schematically, we have $I=e^{\alpha \beta}\operatorname{Ei}_m(\alpha z)$, then using the recurrence $\partial_x \operatorname{Ei}_m(x)=-\operatorname{Ei}_{m-1}(x)$, together with $\partial_x \operatorname{Ei}_1(x)=-e^{x}/x$ one can write the $n$th derivative in terms of the binomial coefficients

Comment: Thank you so much for your enthusiasm !