# $P = \int_0^{\infty}y^{b-1}e^{-\lambda y}(\lambda-sy)^{-b}\text{d}y$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am trying to solve the following integration, but not getting it exactly.

$$P = \int_0^{\infty}y^{b-1}e^{-\lambda y}(\lambda-sy)^{-b}\text{d}y\tag1$$

where $b,s,\lambda$ are constants.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The integral is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207043/how-to-rewrite-int-limits-ab-fracxn-exp-alpha-x-smallx-beta-smal/4207994#4207994)

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir....but its not matching with my question...

Comment: @Saru: It will match your question if you plug in $A=0$ and take $B\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Ok sir.....thank you...

Comment: Still its different from my question....

Comment: Can we use binomial expansion here in $(\lambda-sy)^{-b}$

Comment: Hello all.....isn't there any way to solve such integration manually by hand... I got the answer using Mathematica....but I want to derive it by myself....